# How to find the code of a specific colour for use in kivy?

Tags: python, colors, kivy, kivy-language

Where can I find the four character colour codes for specific colours in kivy. Is it possible to just type "red" like in other languages for example.

Comment: See this [list of colors](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors). And no, you cannot just type `red`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thanks mate